How can I play Widevine encrypted audio in the browser?
I already have everything set up (license, server certificate, media keys, all of that)
I just want to load the entire file into an audio element and have it work.
I can barely even find any documentation on how encryption works with audio/video elements.
I have attempted to use MSE, but it causes a lot of weird arbitrary limitations and problems that don't make any sense. Even when I had everything working, it still threw an error with longer audio, and when I tried to combat that, it would remove the beginning of the audio to append more. I don't want to implement dynamically appending when I seek, as it just adds another layer of confusion and things to deal with.
If I try simply setting the src to the encrypted audio URL, it refuses to play at all.

If you're a licensed user (i.e. content-provider) of Widevine then you should have been provided with SDK access, including their full documentation. In addition to their HTML samples (using their "Shaka" player for <video>) there's also their test-suite which should include coverage for <audio>) - have you had a look and found anything relevant?

I'm attempting to play Widevine encrypted content from a server. I'm not using Shaka or any other libraries, just trying to do it directly with the  element.

Speak to whoever gave you the media-keys and license files and ask them to give you access to the rest of the Widevine documentation then.
